# AppSync Issue with node js and subscribe event function

Tags: node.js, express, backend, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using node js latest version and appsync for the real-time event provided by AWS.

Below is my code I am not getting any notification when I am pushing data from a mutation on any channel name.

This is my generator function

```
const subscribe = (name, next, error) => {
    console.log("call subscribe")
    const subscribeDoc = 
    `subscription Subscribe($name: String!) {
        subscribe(name: $name) {
            data
            name
        }
    }`;
    return API.graphql(graphqlOperation(subscribeDoc, { name })).subscribe({
        next: ({ provider, value }) => {
            next(value.data.subscribe, provider, value)
        },
        error: console.log,
    })
}
```

Calling generator function from helper

```
export const SubscribeHandlerStoreReplyView = async (channelName) => {

    Amplify.configure(config)
    const subscribeChannel =  subscribe(channelName, ({ data }) => {
        console.log("Inside the callback :", data)
    });
    
    console.log("subscribeChannel :",subscribeChannel)
}
```

The output I am getting while connecting with appsync server

```
subscribeChannel : Subscription {
  _cleanup: [Function (anonymous)],
  _observer: { next: [Function: next], error: [Function: log] },
  _queue: undefined,
  _state: 'ready'
}
```

The same code is working while using react js and also I am not sure why the queue is empty in response.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined properly the **subscribeDoc** and **subscribe** Functions. For further implementation check out this reference code [Create AppSyc with node js and subscribe event function](https://github.com/RobinaMirbahar/AWS-Cloud-Solutions/blob/main/AppSyc%20with%20node%20js%20and%20subscribe%20event%20function)

Comment: Doc schema is the same as per the documentation

`const subscribeDoc =
    subscription Subscribe($name: String!) {
        subscribe(name: $name) {
            data
            name
        }
    }
    `

In react I am getting the state value is showing "running" but with node js state is showing "ready"

Comment: Did you check AWS AppSync API endpoint has the IAM permission to subscribe to the endpoint? @Durga

Comment: add the 'try...catch' block in order to handle any errors that occur during the subscription. @Durga

Comment: Yes, end point is working fine on the client side I am using the same configuration on the server side.

Comment: Nothing coming in the catch part code is running properly inside the try.

Comment: Use the API.graphql method as I have mentioned above @Durga

Comment: like this right 
`const subscribeDoc =     \`subscription Subscribe($name: String!) {         subscribe(name: $name) {             data             name         }     }\`; ` . Also tried with this not working same state showing ready

Comment: replace with const subscribeDoc = `subscription SubscribeToChanel ($name: String!) {         subscribe(name: $name) {             data             name         }     }`; @Durga

Comment: My function name is Subscribe on the appsync schema do I need to replace it with your name?

Comment: It's not clear where the mutation is triggered and where the to subscribe function is called from ,add please @Durga

Comment: Its added please verify const subscribeDoc = `\`
        subscription SubscribeToChanel($name: String!) {
            subscribe(name: $name) {
                data
                name
            }
        }\`
        `

Comment: Check out this for reference https://github.com/RobinaMirbahar/AWS-Cloud-Solutions/commit/c06eab02daff7f33ad0415d4349df3c091fd11d0 @Durga

Comment: I tried with your code its working on client side but again not working with server side.

Comment: make sure in this function SubscribeHandlerStoreReplyView 'channelName' argument is string not an object @Durga

Comment: I have added the modified code to the GitHub repository kindly check https://github.com/RobinaMirbahar/AWS-Cloud-Solutions/commit/c06eab02daff7f33ad0415d4349df3c091fd11d0 @Durga

Comment: yes, I am passing the channel name as a string.